# TSQL - How to extract numbers from varchar string

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2).

I have a string of text in the following format:

```
12/07/17 - Amount to pay £580.00 = Rent plus £55.58 per month - MC
```

The values and content will change but it's always in this format.

How do I extract the number value after the word pay. In this case it's '£580.00', but values could vary such as '£20.00' or '£7.50' etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I like John's idea of using an iTVF but there's no need to suffer the expense of a tally based splitter. They're great when you need to parse a string into lots of rows based on a delimiter, but total overkill for something like this.

Here's an alternative that should be much faster and more efficient...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tfn_ExtractPayAmount 
/* =========================================================================
Extracts the monetary amount following the 1st occurrence of the word "pay".
========================================================================= */
(
    @String VARCHAR(800)
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
RETURN
    SELECT 
        RetValue = SUBSTRING(@String, sp.StartPosition, ISNULL(ep.EndPosition - sp.StartPosition, 0))
    FROM 
        ( VALUES (CHARINDEX(' pay ', @String, 1) + 5) ) sp (StartPosition)
        CROSS APPLY ( VALUES (IIF(sp.StartPosition = 5, NULL, CHARINDEX(' ', @String, sp.StartPosition + 1))) ) ep (EndPosition);
GO
```

HTH, Jason

Comment: Plus1 - Tested the performance of your approach on 1MM rows of sample data.  Your performance was 2.566 seconds while mine was 4.778.   That said, I like the multi-functionality my approach has

Comment: I agree. That's always a dilemma... End up with a slew of ultra specific functions or a small(er) number of more flexible functions. In general, I'll start by getting  the function to the job it needs to do and do it as efficiently as I can get it and then see if I can add flexibility w/o compromising efficiency. For example, I could add a @LeadWord parameter to replace the hard coded "for" without any penalty.

Comment: Already took yours and added the start/end parameters.   What can I say?  I'm a card-carrying pirate.  When I see a good idea I steal it.  :)

Comment: Isn't that why we're all here? I'd rather have someone take my solution and improve upon it (so I can incorporate their improvements into my next solution), than skip over it and keep using poor code choices. For example, I still see tally tables being build with loops and recursive CTEs... SMH

Comment: The one thing I would suggest is changing from IIF to a CASE statement. IIF was implemented in SQL Server for one explicit case which was to improve portability from Access. I think sticking to ANSI standard would probably be a better idea in general, but other than that and the SCHEMABINDING I love this answer. SCHEMABINDING can be really troublesome when trying to drop objects that use the UDF.

Comment: Kind words, I appreciate the compliment. As to your concerns... IIf is just a CASE expression w/ an abbreviated syntax. The only reason to use CASE over IIf in this circumstance, is backward comparability for pre-2012 versions. Beyond that, I really couldn't care less about ANSII standards... The idea of code portability between platforms is laughable at best. As to the SCHEMABINDING, since there is no underlying tables, there is nothing actually being bound, it's just there to prevent a potential eager spool operation in the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

If open to a TVF (Table Value Function), consider the following

Tired of extracting strings (left, right, charindex, patindex, ...) I modified a parse function to accept two non-like parameters.  In this case `'pay '` and `' '`.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,SomeCol nvarchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'12/07/17 - Amount to pay £580.00 = Rent plus £55.58 per month - MC')

Select A.*
      ,B.RetVal
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](A.SomeCol,'pay ',' ') B
 Where try_convert(money,B.RetVal) is not null
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter1 varchar(100),@Delimiter2 varchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

with   cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
       cte2(N)   As (Select Top (IsNull(DataLength(@String),0)) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From (Select N=1 From cte1 N1,cte1 N2,cte1 N3,cte1 N4,cte1 N5,cte1 N6) A ),
       cte3(N)   As (Select 1 Union All Select t.N+DataLength(@Delimiter1) From cte2 t Where Substring(@String,t.N,DataLength(@Delimiter1)) = @Delimiter1),
       cte4(N,L) As (Select S.N,IsNull(NullIf(CharIndex(@Delimiter1,@String,s.N),0)-S.N,8000) From cte3 S)

Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By N)
      ,RetPos = N
      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)-1) 
 From  (
        Select *,RetVal = Substring(@String, N, L) 
         From  cte4
       ) A
 Where charindex(@Delimiter2,RetVal)>1

)
/*
Max Length of String 1MM characters

Declare @String varchar(max) = 'Dear [[FirstName]] [[LastName]], ...'
Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract] (@String,'[[',']]')
*/
```

> **EDIT - To Illustrate the Return of Multiple Values**

```
Select A.*
      ,B.RetVal
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Extract](A.SomeCol,'£',' ') B
 Where try_convert(money,B.RetVal) is not null
```

**Returns**

[image]